# word frequency in python not working

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to count frequencies of words in a text file using python.

I am using the following code:

```
openfile=open("total data", "r")

linecount=0
for line in openfile:
    if line.strip():
        linecount+=1

count={}

while linecount>0:
    line=openfile.readline().split()
    for word in line:
        if word in count:
            count[word]+=1
        else:
            count[word]=1
    linecount-=1

print count
```

But i get an empty dictionary. "print count" gives {} as output

I also tried using:

```
from collections import defaultdict
.
.
count=defaultdict(int)
.
.
     if word in count:
          count[word]=count.get(word,0)+1
```

But i'm getting an empty dictionary again. I dont understand what am i doing wrong. Could someone please point out?

Comment: After you count all of the lines the input from the file is exhausted, you need to re-open it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This loop `for line in openfile:` moves the file pointer at the end of the file. 
So, if you want to read the data again then either move the pointer(`openfile.seek(0)`) to the start of the file or re-open the file.

To get the word frequency better use `Collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
with open("total data", "r") as openfile:
   c = Counter()
   for line in openfile:
      words = line.split()
      c.update(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `openfile.seek(0)` right after you initialize `count`.  That'll put the read pointer to the beginning of the file

Answer (score 1):

This is a much more direct way of counting the word frequency in a file:

```
from collections import Counter

def count_words_in_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return Counter(f.read().split())
```

Example:

```
>>> count_words_in_file('C:/Python27/README.txt').most_common(10)
[('the', 395), ('to', 202), ('and', 129), ('is', 120), ('you', 111), ('a', 107), ('of', 102), ('in', 90), ('for', 84), ('Python', 69)]
```