# Counter() is returning 1 for all words. How to get actual count?

Tags: python-3.x, collections, word-frequency

I have a text file that I'm trying to get the most commonly used words with.  I'm using `Counter`, but it just seems to return `1` for each one.

I'm learning, so I'm using the [Simple Sabotage Field Manual](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/26184/pg26184.txt) for my text file.

```
import re
from collections import Counter
my_file = "fieldManual.txt"

#### GLOBAL VARIABLES
lst = [] # used in unique_words
cnt = Counter()

#########

def clean_word(the_word):
    #new_word = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', '',the_word)
    new_word = re.sub('^[^a-zA-z]*|[^a-zA-Z]*$', '', the_word)
    return new_word

def unique_words():
    with open(my_file, encoding="utf8") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            words = line.split()
            for word in words:
                edited_word = clean_word(word)
                if edited_word not in lst:
                    lst.append(edited_word)
                    cnt[edited_word] += 1
    lst.sort()  
    word_count = Counter(lst)
    return(lst)
    return (cnt)

unique_words()
test = ['apple','egg','apple','banana','egg','apple']
print(Counter(lst)) # returns '1' for everything
print(cnt) # same here
```

So, `print(Counter(test))` returns, correctly,

> Counter({'apple': 3, 'egg': 2, 'banana': 1})

But my attempts to print the most frequent words in my `lst` returns

> Counter({'': 1, 'A': 1, 'ACTUAL': 1, 'AGREE': 1, 'AGREEMENT': 1, 'AK': 1, 'AND': 1, 'ANY': 1, 'ANYTHING': 1, 'AR': 1, 'AS-IS': 1, 'ASCII': 1, 'About': 1, 'Abstract': 1, 'Accidentally': 1, 'Act': 1, 'Acts': 1, 'Add': 1, 'Additional': 1, 'Adjust': 1, 'Advocate': 1, 'After': 1, 'Agriculture': 1, ...

Following the answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426673/4650297), I tried adding `cnt.Update(edited_word)` in the `if edited_word not in lst:`, but then printing `cnt` I just get single characters:

> Counter({'e': 2401, 'i': 1634, 't': 1470, 's': 1467, 'n': 1455, 'r': 1442, 'a': 1407, 'o': 1244, 'l': 948, 'c': 862, 'd': 752, 'u': 651, 'p': 590, 'g': 564, 'm': 436, ...

How do I return the frequency of each unique word from my .txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only append the word to the list if it isn't already found. As such, every word will only show up once.

Comment: [Oh...my...goodness](http://gif-finder.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Steve-Carell-Facepalm.gif). Thanks so much for pointing that, now super obvious, point. That'll do it!  I was way overthinking this and didn't step back and go through it out loud...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here. You should either increment the counter regardless of whether the word is in the list, or just call the counter on the list from the split string. You have back to back return statements(the second won't be executed). You are finding the count of the list with `word_count` and then ignoring that output(which would also be 1 for every word). Just cleaning up this code probably would have helped solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I'm learning Python (obviously I suppose) and was just trying to get this working, then will be going back through to make it tighter, and perhaps even head to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Also, thanks for the note on `return`, I'll put those on the same line.